# Can't pip install llama-index in fresh virtual environment running python 3.12.x -- potential issues with onnxruntime

Tags: pip, large-language-model, llama-index, package-management, python-3.12

Attempts to install llama-index in a fresh virtual environment (using conda) returns the following:

```
conda create --name llm-3.12 python=3.12
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install llama-index (failed)
pip install llama-index --no-cache --force-reinstall (also failed, same error*)
```

```
ERROR: Cannot install llama-index-cli because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    llama-index-vector-stores-chroma 0.1.4 depends on onnxruntime<2.0.0 and >=1.17.0
    llama-index-vector-stores-chroma 0.1.3 depends on onnxruntime<2.0.0 and >=1.17.0
    llama-index-vector-stores-chroma 0.1.2 depends on onnxruntime<2.0.0 and >=1.17.0
    llama-index-vector-stores-chroma 0.1.1 depends on onnxruntime<2.0.0 and >=1.17.0
```

I do not have any version of onnxruntime installed. Attempting to install [onnxruntime](https://pypi.org/project/onnxruntime/) manually, using pip, fails:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnxruntime (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for onnxruntime
```

Attempting to install llama-index in python 3.12. Cannot do so. Listed packages that are requirements (onnxruntime) are not currently available on pypi.

Comment: `onnxruntime` [is available on PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/onnxruntime/#files), but either not for your operating system, or you have other issues. What is your operating system? Have you actually activated your conda environment, becuase your steps do not include that part

Comment: I have the same issues on OSX 14.3.1